# Rails: initializing global variable in event_mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendmail

In my mailers/event_mailer class, I have a few methods. Each of these methods:

1. Receives a user hash an input
2. Turns the user hash into a global variable
3. calls a the corresponding .html.erb file from event_mailers to send email

Instead of repeating steps 1 & 2 for every method, is there a way to have that initialized once in a "constructor" for the event_mailer class?

## Clarification Code:

Registrations Controller Code:

```
          EventMailer.notify_admins(@user,subject,topic).deliver
```

event_mailer.rb code:

```
class EventMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  @@smtp_settings = {
  ..........
  }

def notify_admins(user,subject,topic)
    @user = user
    @topic = topic
    ......
    mail(:from => 'test@example.com', :to => 'someone@someone.com', :subject => subject)
end

def notify_accounts(user,subject,topic)
    @user = user
    @topic = topic
    ......
    mail(:from => 'test@example.com', :to => 'someone@someone.com', :subject => subject)
end
```

Comment: Can you show your code for steps 1 & 2?

Comment: This is not really about the specific code in 1&2, but I posted a sample from the code